# iText build using Maven issue with not finding iText package

Tags: java, maven, itext

I am trying out iText using maven to build the Java application.
I get the following error when i run mvn package

```
[ERROR] /C:/maven_projects/pdf-app/src/main/java/com/my-app/app/App.java:[7,25] package itextpdf.html2pdf does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/maven_projects/pdf-app/src/main/java/com/my-app/app/App.java:[19,9] cannot find symbol
symbol:   variable HtmlConverter
location: class com.my-app.app.App
```

So looking at this error where should the iText Jar file exist, it currently sits in the target/dependency folder. so i'm guessing it can't find the file from the error or is there more to this.

Any help appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: can you do a `mvn clean package` or `mvn clean install`? and then if you are using eclispe then do a `right-click on your project then Maven > Update Snapshots.`

Comment: Tried both and still getting the same errors unfortunately

Comment: OK, basically Maven dependencies are also stored in Maven Dependencies Folder.

Comment: *"package itextpdf.html2pdf does not exist"* - that is plausible, none of the official iText / Java artifacts has such a package. The iText 7 `html2pdf` artifact has a `com.itextpdf.html2pdf` package, though. Have you probably forgotten that leading `com.` in your imports?

Comment: Add the dependencies section of your `pom.xml` file, and the imports of your `.java` file.